# How to print two or more plots in one graph using C and gnuplot

Tags: c, plot, graph, gnuplot

I'm kinda new to C and I want to plot data in C using gnuplot. For now I have this code:

```
FILE *gnuplot = popen("gnuplot", "w");
fprintf(gnuplot, "plot '-' lc 6 w lp\n");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    fprintf(gnuplot, "%g %g \n", x[i], y[i] );
}
fprintf(gnuplot, "e\n");
fflush(gnuplot);
```

It prints one plot at a time and works just fine, however I need to plot **two graphs** at the same time in the same coordinates. Is there a way to include some lines of code to my program or I should use completely different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use inline data blocks (page 46 in the [manual](http://gnuplot.info/docs_5.4/Gnuplot_5_4.pdf)), e.g.:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int size = 10;
  FILE *gnuplot = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");

  fprintf(gnuplot, "$MyData << EOD\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    fprintf(gnuplot, "%d %d\n", i, size-i );
  }

  fprintf(gnuplot, "EOD\n");

  fprintf(gnuplot, "plot $MyData u 0:1 lc 6 w lp, $MyData u 0:2 w l\n");
  fflush(gnuplot);
  return 0;
}
```

[image: Plot of 2 lines crossing]